# Shutting down SSL without closing underlying socket?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

How can I gracefully shutdown a Java SSL session without closing the underlying socket?

The scenario is that a Java client connects to a (non-java) server, sets up SSL and securely sends credentials (user name & password) to the server. The server sets up an environment running under these credentials, spawns a new process in this environment and passes the socket handle to it, but the catch is that this new process can't reuse the existing SSL connection (and can't use SSL session resuming)... so the idea is to shutdown SSL before this new process is spawned, and then re-negotiate an SSL session from scratch with the new process.

The problem is that Java's [SSLSocket's](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html) `close()` method closes the socket in addition to shutting down the SSL session (by [sending the close_notify alert](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2.1)). There doesn't seem to be an equivalent of OpenSSL's [SSL_shutdown()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_shutdown.html) function, which allows leaving the underlying socket open.

I have tried a few things to get around this:

1. Using [SSLSocket.startHandshake()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#startHandshake()) a second time, but that automatically tries to resume the existing cached SSL session (which fails, since the spawned server process does not know of this session), and, while there is a method to [force resuming SSL sessions or die trying](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html#setEnableSessionCreation(boolean)), there is no method to invalidate all cached sessions or disable use of cached sessions.
2. Creating an `SSLSocket` over the top of my existing socket using [SSLSocketFactory.createSocket()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#createSocket%28java.net.Socket,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20boolean%29), with `autoClose` set to false. This does not stop the `close()` method from closing the underlying socket, and I suspect that the `autoClose` parameter only prevents the socket from being closed when the initial handshake fails.
3. Creating an `SSLSocket` over an existing socket (as above), then creating a second `SSLSocket` to use for the SSL handshake with the spawned process (from a new [SSLContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html)). This fails because when the server sends the `close_notify` alert (before spawning the sub-process), Java closes the socket.

I have heard of [SSLEngine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html), but I have also read (though the source currently eludes me) that it is a lot of painful effort to write a correct implementation of SSL over TCP/IP using it, and it seems like overkill when all I need is to have a version of `SSLSocket` whose `close()` doesn't call `super.Close()`.

However, `SSLSocket` does not appear to even override `close()` (according to the javadoc), so I am unsure as to how it hooks the `close()` method when there does not appear to be any support for registering close listeners on `Socket`.

Company policy dictates that no third-party encryption libraries can be used, so I cannot turn to an alternative SSL implementation such as that by [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) to solve the problem.

If we can't get the current 1-socket design to work, the alternative is to rewrite the client & server to use 2 separate sockets (which gets quite messy in terms of having to counter denial of service and man-in-the-middle attacks, and isn't that what SSL is supposed to be for in the first place?).

Any input or thoughts on ways to solve this problem would be most welcome.

Comment: Did you try to use a normal Socket in the background? Something like: `Socket s = new Socket(HOST, PORT); SSLSocket ssl = ...; ssl.connect(s.getRemoteSocketAddress()); ...` ? (for me at least it does not close the "underlying" socket.. *probably I'm doing something wrong* :) )

Comment: dacwe, as near as I can tell (ignoring the ... part of your snippet), doing ssl.connect() will create a second connection to the host, and the socket `s` will not be used at all for the SSL communications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This does not stop the close() method
>   from closing the underlying socket

Yes it does. As per the documentation.

> and I suspect that the autoClose
>   parameter only prevents the socket
>   from being closed when the initial
>   handshake fails.

No. It prevents closing of the underlying socket. As per the documentation.

Show us some code.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct. `SSLSocket.close()` javadoc may not say anything about shutting down SSL communications and the Eclipse outline view of `SSLSocket` doesn't show a `close` method (maybe it doesn't show overridden methods for compiled classes without source attachments), but somehow `SSLSocket.close()` does override the functionality of `Socket.close()`.

Comment: SSLSocket is abstract. The implementation class overrides close().

Comment: Yeah. I agree it should be documented and that it sends a close_notify, and that startHandshake() or the first I/O causes the client end to send a client hello, etc. In fact would like to see more of this kind of documentation generally, even for Sockets, e.g. that Socket.connect() starts the SYN sequence, SocketChannel.finishConnect() tells you whether the ACK to the SYN has been received, shutdownOutput() and close() start the FIN/ACK sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a plain underlying socket (your #3), as this is what implementations of FTP with Clear Control Channel do.

Keep in mind that what you are trying to do leaves you open for a man-in-the-middle attack between the two SSL sessions unless you carry some secret between the two to signal that the authentication is still valid.

1. Use network naughtiness (ARP poisoning?) to become a proxy between the client and server.
2. Forward packets both directions until the authentication completes and the SSL session ends.  (Any SSL ALERT will signal the end, we don't need to decrypt the contents).
3. Close the socket to the client so it will error out.
4. Do my own SSL negotiation with the server.
5. Proceed to operate with the client's credentials.

Comment: EJP answered my question better, but +1 for pointing out a MITM attack which I hadn't thought of.